# is bounded linear operator necessarily continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $U, V$ be separable Banach spaces.

Suppose we have a bounded, linear operator
$C : U\to V$.

Questions are the following

- Shall $C$ be continuous since $V$ is a Banach space?
- In general, is a bounded linear operator necessarily continuous (I guess the answer is no, but what would be a counter example?)
- Are things in Banach spaces always continuous?

Comment: Bounded linear operators are continuous. (Think about how Lipschitz condition implies uniform continuity for functions on real line). Things in Banach spaces aren't always continuous though.

Comment: actually why don't we directly learn: "bounded linear operators" equivalent to "Lipschitz continuous one", but only equivalent to continuous ones?

Comment: @user27126: Is every continuous operator bounded? I know the answer is yes in finite-dimensional spaces, but how about in infinite-dimensional ones? I am thinking maybe, e.g., the differentiation operator which I know is unbounded is also continuous?

Comment: Differentiation is not necessarily continuous, consider the space of smooth 2 $\pi$ periodic functions and the sequence sin(nx)/x and the sup-norm.

Answer (score 20):

An operator $C$ is bounded *iff* the set {$\|Cx\|:\|x\|\leq 1$} is bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ there is a $M<\infty:\|Cx\|\leq M\|x\|$ for every $x\in U$.

Let $ε>0$. If $x,y\in U:\|x-y\|<ε/M$, then $$\|Cx-Cy\|=\|C(x-y)\|\leq M\|x-y\|<\varepsilon.$$ Thus $C$ is not only continuous but uniformly continuous also.

So, a bounded operator is always continuous on norm-spaces. Banach space is a norm-space which is complete, thus things are not different there.

Answer (score 3):

This property is unrelated to the completeness of the domain or range, but instead only to the linear nature of the operator. Yes, a linear operator (between normed spaces) is bounded [if and only if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) it is continuous.

**Added** @Dimitris's answer prompted me to mention, beyond the fact that the implication on normed spaces indeed is an equivalence, that it's the *converse* which holds in the wider context of topological vector spaces, while the proposition mentioned here fails: there [are](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/441646/89121) bounded discontinuous linear operators, yet every continuous operator remains bounded.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan and Sanchez.In this case, so instead of saying "a bounded linear operator $C: U\to V$", one can say $C\in\mathcal{L}(U,V)$, where $\mathcal{L}(U,V)=\{C: U\to V\,\,|\,\, C\,\,\text{is linear and continuous}\}$?

Comment: You may, only I've only seen this notation used as a synonym of $\mathrm{Hom}(U,V)$, the space of *all* linear maps between them. Perhaps another notation would serve you better.

Comment: $\text{Hom}(X,Y)=\{C: U\to V\,\,|\,C\,\,\text{is linear}\}$, which means $C$ is not necessarily continuous. In finite dimensions, the two notations are the same. But this is not true in infinite dimensions. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You're correct. I was saying I've only seen $\mathcal{L}(U,V)$ being used as an alternate notation to $\mathrm{Hom}(U,V)$.

Comment: The standard notation that I have encountered is $B(U,V)$, meaning the space of bounded linear operators that map the entirety of the linear space $U$ into some/all of the linear space $V$. This is identical to the space of continuous linear operators $U\rightarrow V$. When $U=V$ then it is simply notated $B(V)$.