# Superposition principle with infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces and let $L: X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Suppose that $x_k\in X, k\in \mathbb N$ and $\sum_k x_k$ converges. Prove that $L(\sum_k x_k) = \sum_k L(x_k)$.

I'm wondering if my approach is correct.

> Since $L$ is bounded, there is $M>0$ such that $\|L(x)\|\le M\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$. Since $\sum_k x_k$ converges, $L(\sum_k x_k)$ converges.

Now,

$$\left\|L(\sum\limits_{k=1}^N x_k)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^N L(x_k)\right\|=\left\|L(x_1)+\dots+L(x_N)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^N L(x_k)\right\|=\left\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^N L( x_k)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^N L(x_k)\right\|=0$$

I'm wondering if this proof is rigorous, since we have that the series are equal for finite $N$, but does this show it is equal for infinite $N$?

Comment: I think you mean $\|L(x)\|\leq M\|x\|$, otherwise the assertion is false.

Comment: Also you haven't really shown $L(\sum_kx_k)=\sum_kL(x_k)$. You need to show that $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} L(\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k)=L(\sum_kx_k)$, i.e. that the limit can be passed through the operator. This has to involve considering $L(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty x_k)$ at some point.

Comment: @AlexR. Can you please give a hint how to prove that the limit can be passed through the operator? Moreover, if one proves this, how does this imply the result to be proved?

Also, can you please clarify how I've also fixed the boundedness definition part as you've pointed out.

Comment: Are we assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces?

Comment: Actually I don't think $Y$ needs to be a Banach space. Linear operators are bounded iff they are continuous, so the continuous image of a convergent sequence should be convergent. I suppose all that needs to be shown is that the two limits are equal.

Comment: @Math1000 Can you please point out a theorem which says that bounded linear operators must be continuous?

Comment: @sequence It is a fundamental theorem in operator theory; see here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/556667

Comment: @Math1000 Then, I think, we can say that $L(x_0)=L(\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \sum_k^N x_k)=\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} L(\sum_k^N x_k)= \lim\limits_{N\to \infty} [L(x_1)+\dots+L(x_N)]= \lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \sum_k^N L(x_k) $. Do you think this is correct?